# What does max subcript mean?

Tags: java

What does a max subscript mean in Java? Is it to find max length?
I know it will always start from -1 but what does it really mean?

Comment: Maximum subscript of an array , i was told.

Comment: *I know it will always start from -1* who said ?

Comment: My lecturer said it.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You should ask these questions to your lecturer only.

Comment: Then you need a new lecturer, or you misunderstood. Array indexes start at 0, not -1; the max subscript of an array is its length - 1 (since we start counting with 0). If you have an `int[5]`, the array indexes are 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4.

Comment: I knew array start from 0.

Answer (score 0):

Array indexes start at 0; the max subscript of an array is its `length - 1` (since we start counting with 0). If you have an `int[5]`, the array indexes are 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4.